# Present modally in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to do a modal presentation of a route in Flutter?

I figured out how to navigate to a route using the usual "push" transition, but I am struggling to implement a modal transition. See animation attached (done using native iOS). How do I present a screen modally (a screen that itself can be pushed more screens to).

See an example below. The transition I am struggling with is from "A" to "C" (and of course a way to dismiss it and go back to "A").

[image]

Comment: You may want to take a look at MaterialPageRoute, CupertinoPageRoute and PageRouteBuilder

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can push like this:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
        CupertinoPageRoute(
                fullscreenDialog: true,
                builder: (context) => SomePage(),
        ),
);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: **fullscreenDialog: true**

Answer (score 36):

Go to **Section B**(push) animation can be achieved by following:

```
Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SectionBRoute()),
              );
```

Go to **Section C**(present modally) animation can be achieved by following:

```
Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SectionCRoute(), fullscreenDialog: true),
              );
```